# php files not running inside CI fodlers

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have included the CKEditor and CKFinder libraries in my CI folder structure.
Its inside "user_data" folder. But when i try to access its file, it give 404 error. Following is the folder structure :-

```
application
    - controller
    - models
    - views
    - etc..
system
user_data
    - assets
        - plugins
            - ckfinder
            - ckeditor
            - phpinfo.php
```

i can go till path "plugins/ckfinder", but not able to access its files. it gives 404 error. for confirmation i added phpinfo.php, in same folder, but it also gave same error. So

```
https://sitename/user_data/assets/plugins/
```

gives / displays the inside files and folders but,
    https://sitename/user_data/assets/plugins/phpinfo.php

gives 404 error.
i have only one htacess file in root folder, means with application folder.
Please provide me some suggestion on how to solve this. i treid by putting it in controller or libraries folder also. but same output.

===== UPDATE =======
I am trying to uplaod the image to server through ckfinder and getting the 404 error when uploading the image. For confirmation if ckfinder files are accessible i tried for above case. Below is my code.

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>CKEditor CKFinder Integration using PHP</h1>
        <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        filebrowserBrowseUrl : 'http://stename/user_data/assets/plugins/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
        filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : 'http://stename/user_data/assets/plugins/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
        filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl : 'http://stename/user_data/assets/plugins/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash',
        filebrowserUploadUrl : 'http://stename/assets/user_data/plugins/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
        filebrowserImageUploadUrl : 'http://stename/user_data/assets/plugins/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images',
        filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : 'http://stename/user_data/assets/plugins/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash'
    });
    CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, '../' );
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks,

Comment: `plugins` it in `assest` folder

Comment: yes, plugins is in assests folder.

Comment: then access like this `https://sitename/user_data/assest/plugins/`

Comment: @Purushottamzende What you need?? access file or load `ckfinder` and `ckeditor`??

Comment: @Abdulla, i want to work with ckfinder upload image functionality, but its connector file is not accesible to the server. it gives 404 error in image upload dialog. so i checked if its files accesible and found that they are accessible.

Comment: @PathikVejani, sorry, it was by mistake, i have changed the access link. it is same as you said.

Comment: Add root directory `.htaccess` file code.

Comment: @Tpojka, which code, mu htacess is full of 301 and url transfers. i am putting only code by which we cans kip index.php files and user caanot view directory structure.
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

 Options -Indexes

Comment: Before those conditions put line `RewriteCond $1 !^user_data`.

Comment: @Tpojka, nope, still same response

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>user_data/assets/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>user_data/assets/plugins/ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
```

> Make sure URL library is loaded.

Comment: i can see the proper text editor with all the options, but while uploading the image from editor it gives 404 error. when debugged, connection.php file was not accessible. so figuring out why its not available.

Comment: whats that `connection.php`??

Comment: sorry, "ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files" this is my ckeditor path, and gives error to this as 404.

Comment: No its wrong. If you download CkEditor in root there is file call `ckeditor.js`. You have to only call that.

Comment: yes, that calls library, but we need above file and path, to upload files and structure to server. LIke

CKEDITOR.replace( 'emailContent', ... );

Comment: I Cant understand what your purpose

Comment: i have updated the question. please check. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Purushottamzende this path is wrong `http://stename/assets/plugins/ckfinder/ckfinder.html`. **There is no `user_data` folder**

Comment: i updated the question again. actually i treid so many things, that i am confusing myself.

Comment: Set path like this `<?php echo base_url() ?>user_data/assets/plugins/ckfinder/ckfinder.html`

Comment: yes i am using the same thing, its just source  code.

Comment: so what error?? all works fine as i know. Cz i have using same

Comment: yes but it shows error, 404. When uploading the image ( when click on "send to server" ).

Comment: Check your path of sending data. Include `index.php` as well

Comment: but its in different folder outside application folder, then how can i add index.php to it. Also, folder structure is visible, but when i click on any of the php file in the folder it shows 404 error.